# SQLite Query to get certain Value

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Database, I have the follwoing data stored:

```
_id | NumericalEquivalents | ValTo | valFrom | Section
------------------------------------------------------
 1            1.00            100     99          a
 2            1.25            98      96          a
 3            1.75            95      93          a
 .....
 .....
 10           5.00            74      0           a
```

Now in my app, the grade will be computed programatically, and I have the code below to get the Numerical Equivalent of the computed grade:

```
public float getNumEqui(String sect, float grade)
            {

                String q = "SELECT * FROM NumericalEquivalents where Section='"+sect+"' and valTo>="+grade+" and valFrom<="+grade;

                 Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(q, null);
                 if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                     float reset= cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("NumericalEquivalent"));
                        return reset;
                    }  
                    //return sometotal;

             return -1;

            }
```

My problem now is that it always return 5.00, I was wondering if something was wrong with the query that I used. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess your grade is 0

Comment: I tried setting different grades, the result is always the same.

Comment: If you test it with section 'a' and grade 90, what will be the result?

Comment: the result is still 5.0

Comment: What is the result with 99?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM NumericalEquivalents  
where Section = 'a' and @grade between ValFrom and ValTo
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2f737/4)